# How do you close the previous accordion item when clicking on the next one

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, accordion

For some reason, my previous accordion items are not automatically closing when clicking on the next item. I thought this was done by default.

Here is my HTML:

```
<div class="container top-section">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <div class="col-md-9 homewelcome">
        <div id="accordian">
         <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
    contentone
</div>
    <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingTwo">
  contenttwo
</div>
    <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingThree">
  contentthree
</div>
        </div>
        </div>

    <div class="col-md-3 remove-padding">
        <ul class="reset-list colour-options">
            <a href="#collapseOne" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" title="Young Carer"><li class="blue first-blue">Young Carer</li></a>
            <a href="#collapseTwo" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" title="What we do"><li class="pink first-pink">What we do</li></a>
            <a href="#collapseThree" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" title="Info for families"><li class="blue blue-second">Info for<br>families</li></a>
            <a href="/" title="Info for professionals" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion"><li class="pink pink-second">Info for<br>professionals</li></a>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Probably because of data-parent="#accordion" and id="accordian". There is a typo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not done by default but binding to the collapse event and hiding the rest of the collapsible elements using jQuery will do the trick. See [Boostrap javascript docs](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse-events)

```
var $topSection = $('.top-section');
$topSection.on('show.bs.collapse','.collapse', function() {
    $topSection.find('.collapse.in').collapse('hide');
});
```

**Bootply**
http://www.bootply.com/Kg6K0W7rJg